# How to extract a picture from an xlsx file using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, xlsx

When i trying to extract an image from an xlsx file, either nil or nothing is returned

I tried to use such gems as clack, spreadsheet, roo, caxlsx and did cell sorting in a loop. All the gems except roo did not even enter the cell with the photo, roo himself returned nil when switching to this cell.

Comment: Then there are probably mistake(s) in your code; without seeing *any* of that, can't be more specific.

Comment: I have no idea what `clack` is and `caxlsx` is for writing xlsx files not reading them and `spreadsheet` creator mentions that image extraction is not supported. `roo` appears to have a way to access images [Docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/roo/2.10.0/Roo/Excelx/Sheet#images-instance_method) but I have never tested this and you have not provided any code for how you are going about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.